# Recent images from twitter profile

Tags: javascript, php, api, twitter

I've extensively searched on Stackoverflow and the web over the last couple of days and I haven't seemed to find any solid answers yet. Is it possible to embed a users latest 6 images using PHP or JS? I've found solutions but they're outdated and using the old API.

Has anyone ever had any luck with this kind of thing?

Comment: What does Twitter's API doc says?